# R - Error in charToDate(x)

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm sure this is super simple to understand, but I'm new to R, and try as I might, I can't get the other suggestions on these forums to work for me.  I'm just trying to download the PAYEMS time series through the Quantmod package.

The code:

```
library(quantmod) 
library(lubridate) 

getSymbols("PAYEMS", src=("FRED"), return.class = "xts")
```

The output:

getSymbols("PAYEMS", src=("FRED"), return.class = "xts")
   Error in charToDate(x) : 
   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I'm guessing it's the date format, but it's not clear to me how I fix that.  I only know how to change it once I get the vector I want to make into dates.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It's probably a dependency issue; from the `quantmod` DESCRIPTION file:  **Depends:** xts(>= 0.9-0), zoo, TTR(>= 0.2), methods  
**Suggests:** DBI,RMySQL,RSQLite,timeSeries,its,XML,downloader

Comment: Not sure I follow.  I installed those packages to see if that would help.  No dice.  How would you recommend I go about fixing the problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, so I can only speculate. If everything is installed and up to date, you can try `traceback()` or debugging to see if you can find out what's causing the problem, but given the code works for me, it's probably some sort of configuration issue, not a code issue, so that approach may not give you an obvious answer.

Comment: I had the same error when accidentally using a non-existing date such as "2017-06-31". A non-standard quote character could also be a reason for the error...

Answer (score 0):

I get this error occasionally too. I don't recall getting this the year before. Restarting R doesn't help, but restarting the computer does solve the problem. I don't know what it is that fixed this.